# Waiting for a copy event

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, cut-copy-paste

I have the following function:

```
function _X()
    normal! gvy
    vs tmp
    normal!p
    ALEFix black
    normal! ggVG
    normal! y <-------
endfunc
```

Unfortunately, the `y` does not work. That is, when it runs within the function whatever it copies is not correct (as if the function didn't finish the job yet). However, as soon as the function exits I can press `y` and it will copy the selection, but not within the function. What's going on here, and how can I fix that behavior?

Comment: PS the ex version of `ggVGy` is `:%yank`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALE's [readme](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) says

> ALE offers support for fixing code with command line tools in a non-blocking manner with the :ALEFix feature

so `ALEFix` is asynchronous and your yanking commands would need to wait for it to complete before they run.

If you look further in the Readme in the FAQ there is [How can I execute some code when ALE starts or stops linting?](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale#5x-how-can-i-execute-some-code-when-ale-starts-or-stops-linting) The plugin provides autocommands to handle this kind of situations:

```
augroup YourGroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd User ALELintPre    call YourFunction()
    autocmd User ALELintPost   call YourFunction()

    autocmd User ALEJobStarted call YourFunction()

    autocmd User ALEFixPre     call YourFunction()
    autocmd User ALEFixPost    call YourFunction()
augroup END
```

Here you'll probably need to use `ALEFixPost` to run your yanking.